# My .NET database has both an IdentityUser and an AspNetUsers table

Tags: .net, asp.net-identity

My newish .NET 6 / Blazor app has both an `IdentityUser` and an `AspNetUsers` table. They have the same columns. I thought I was following along with the docs. I have neither entity as a class in *my* code.

I created the identity via scaffolding. Why do I have both?

```
public class AppIdentityContext : IdentityDbContext<IdentityUser>
{
    public AppIdentityContext(DbContextOptions<AppIdentityContext> options)
    : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

```
// Program.cs, what I hope are the relevant bits.

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("VoidHeistDbContextConnection");

// Database and Identity Services
builder.Services.AddDbContext<AppIdentityContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
builder.Services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();
builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<AppIdentityContext>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<AuthenticationStateProvider, RevalidatingIdentityAuthenticationStateProvider<IdentityUser>>();
builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe you did this.

AspNetUsers inherit IdentityUser

**however. It can't be other than except for this issue**

```
public class AspnetUsers : IdentityUser
{

}
```

Comment: As I said, neither of the classes are in my code. AspNetUsers I assume comes from scaffolded code? But I have no .cs files with those classes defined in them.

Comment: it's impossible @ParkerHarrisEmerson. maybe you have been using the other reference in your project.
be sure to check namespace "IdentityUser" and "AspNetUsers" in your project.

Comment: @ParkerHarrisEmerson

Comment: When I search my project, I get zero hits for `AspNetUser` outside of my migrations. I reference IdentityUser, but do not define it. It's a blazor project, if that matters.

Comment: can I see your sample project in the GitHub public link? @ParkerHarrisEmerson